# How to feature test Cache Lock Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, exception, caching, phpunit

I'm working using Laravel's cache lock and I'm doing a test manually using 2 browsers to make sure if within 10 seconds the first process hasn't finished, then the second process will get a response abort status code 429, and this works as expected, but I'm confused about how to do a feature test for this case.

Here are my controllers:

```
try {
        
    Cache::lock('lock-payment')->block(10 , function() 
    use($pricing_order , $data_order , $vaNumber , $vaPayment , &$message)
    {  
       sleep(11) 
      //another action
    });

   
    } catch (LockTimeoutException $e) {
        return $e->failed();
    }
```

On LockTimeOutExcetion

```
public function failed()
{
    abort(429);
}
```

And the following tests don't run as expected because the tests are executed sequentially,whereas I want the 2nd hit to return status 429.

```
 public function test_ensure_cache_lock_throw_429_status_code() : void
{
    $order = PricingOrder::factory()->create([
        'transaction_status' => 'pending',
        'user_id' => $this->customer->id,
      ]);

    //first hit
    $payload = $this->set_payload(201 , 'settlement'); 
  
    $payload = json_encode($payload);
   
    $this->actingAs($this->customer)->put(route('payment' , $order->order_id) , [
        'order' => $payload
    ])->assertStatus(302); 

    //second hit should throw 429
    $payload = $this->set_payload(201 , 'settlement'); 
  
    $payload = json_encode($payload);
   
    $this->actingAs($this->customer)->put(route('payment' , $order->order_id) , [
        'order' => $payload
    ])->assertStatus(429); 
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing is not about testing how systems act together, but how a single action acts. That why you gotta mock, stub or similar every outside dependency, in this context the cache.

To do that approach obtain the lock in the test before it is called, that way you can test it.

```
public function test_ensure_cache_lock_throw_429_status_code() : void
{
    $lock = Cache::lock('lock-payment', 30);

    $lock->get();

    .. // do your things

    $this->actingAs($this->customer)->put(...);

    // assertions

    $lock->release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but the feature test is different from the unit test right? so I thought of doing a test for related actions

Comment: In litterature feature testing is where you test the whole system from the outside like an actual user, this often means using a browser emulator and navigating the web app like using selenium or similar. Laravel has taken a stance, where they call a test against an emulated application is a feature test, which in my opinion is actually closer to a unit test than a feature test. Also all the tests running in PHPunit can be considered a unit test, terefor the name. So i think it is just a semantic discussion.

Comment: Ahh okay, now i got new information. And Thanks for you answer it works great :)

Comment: @nikkiSix I hate the discussion about what is a test, what a unit test, what an integration test, etc. But, as mrhn said, Laravel sees _Feature_ tests as anything from their system, for example, an HTTP test (`$this->get(...)` or `$this->post(...)`, etc), console tests (`$this->artisan(...)`), [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk) for front-end testing, and more. A _unit_ test is (for Laravel) either a test that only tests isolated features, for example, a Job, a Listener, an Event, etc. And you also have a literal PHPUnit test (parent class is PHPUnit class, not Laravel case).

Comment: You then, also have _Unit_ tests extending the Laravel `TestCase` class (so Laravel is available), and you test a custom class that uses Laravel functions (helpers) or Laravel features like _Dependency Injection_, for example. I do put service class tests (do not confuse with `ServiceProviders`) inside the `Unit` tests folder, as it is an isolated class. Then you also have _Integration_ tests, (for Laravel) they are tests where you literally call external APIs or similar, using "sandbox" credentials/endpoints if available, but you literally test the external service.

Comment: @matiaslauriti So if I want to test an external API service like a payment gateway that is integrated with my app, do I have to create a fake response that resembles the original response given when I hit the API payment gateway endpoint?, if using "sandbox" it means I have to create routes and controllers are different from the "production" version and testing will be done with the "sandbox" version of the controller, maybe something like that?

Comment: @nikkiSix no, sandbox is when a system offers a second user and password or token that gives you access to the same service but on another account that is just for testing purposes, that account is not ment for production but just you testing their system manually or with annautomayed test, try to google it and you will find more info

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks, information that you provide is very useful for me which in begginer stage 